# Sqlite - Update table rows based on another data in the row

Tags: database, sqlite

I'm looking for the way how to update the empty values, based on the similar value from another row:

[image: Pic1]

As you can see from the image: *rowid* with a number (331) contains the website value (tbe.com), but two another rows marked as '?'. I want to sync the data if some of the rows marked '?' for equal company names.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If actually there are `NULL`s in the column `website` instead of `?` then

```
UPDATE tablename AS t1
SET website = (SELECT MAX(t2.website) FROM tablename t2 WHERE t2.company = t1.company)
WHERE t1.website IS NULL
```

If there are `?`:

```
UPDATE tablename AS t1
SET website = COALESCE((
  SELECT MAX(t2.website) 
  FROM tablename t2 
  WHERE t2.company = t1.company AND t2.website <> t1.website
), t1.website)
WHERE t1.website = '?'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable t1
SET website = (SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN t2.website <> '?'
                               THEN t2.website END)
               FROM yourTable t2
               WHERE t2.rowid = t1.rowid);
```